# User account unreachable after migration to D7

Tags: users, migrations

I have this weird problem. After migrating to D7, few of the users can not access their accounts so that they can track or change their passwords. They get 404 error instead. They can otherwise use the site as other uses. I am wondering what may have caused this, and how to fix it?

Comment: have they been migrated properly, i.e. how do their entries look in the users table? Are there path aliases for the user accounts? Do these users have correct path aliases?

Comment: @olyN not sure hot to check integrity of the entry in  DB. I can access the user row in the DB. I use clean urls and all users are aliased. Only very few have this problem.

Comment: I was simply thinking you could compare the rows for some users that has and some that don't have the problem. Have you tried using the system path (user/%uid) to access their accounts?

Comment: @olyN I get the same 404 at user/%uid. What fields of the user row should I compare with other users for hints of corrupted data?

Comment: Just compare all of them. Also look for missing fields.  You could try to do a <?php $u = user_load($uid);?> where $uid is one of the problematic uid's. and then <?php print '<pre>';print_r($u);print '</pre'>; ?> in a custom module or a template file, just to see what happens.